# .htaccess redirect http to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have an old url (`www1.test.net`) and I would like to redirect it to `https://www1.test.net`
I have implemented and installed our SSL certificate on my site.
This is my old file `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !\.(js|gif|jpg|png|css|txt)$ public/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

How can I configure my `.htaccess` file so that url auto redirect to `https`?
Thanks!

Comment: If the second line is intended to not do a redirect if the path points to an actual file (and you're listing the expected possible extensions), you could make it more flexible by replacing it with a check for an existing file: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f ` followed by your redirect.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

**Update 2016**

As this answer receives some attention, I want to hint to a more recommended way on doing this using Virtual Hosts: [Apache: Redirect SSL](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName mysite.example.com
   Redirect permanent / https://mysite.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
   ServerName mysite.example.com
   DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
   SSLEngine On
# etc...
</VirtualHost>
```

**Old answer, hacky thing**
given that your ssl-port is not set to 80, this will work:

```
RewriteEngine on

# force ssl
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Note that this should be your first rewrite rule.

**Edit:** This code does the following. The RewriteCond(ition) checks wether the ServerPort of the request is 80 (which is the default http-port, if you specified another port, you would have to adjust the condition to it). If so, we match the whole url `(.*)` and redirect it to a https-url. `%{SERVER_NAME}` may be replaced with a specific url, but this way you don't have to alter the code for other projects. `%{REQUEST_URI}` is the portion of the url after the TLD (top-level-domain), so you will be redirected to where you came from, but as https.

Comment: I'm getting 403 Forbidden when I try this. Any idea why?

Comment: Where can I find this file in virtual hosts

Comment: To add to the explanation. "[The [L] flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set." Usually you want to just add this by default. "Use of [the [R] flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) causes an HTTP redirect to be issued to the browser." If absent, the redirect will be internal which would void the meaning of using HTTPS. By default, the issued redirect is with status 302 (temporary redirection). If you want the browser to ("permanently") cache the new URL, use `[R=301]` instead.

Comment: For the VirtualHost solution, it's not clear where the "Redirect permanent" statement should be placed in case of a complicated setup. I assumed near the top, and it worked.

Comment: it worked. we need to add the script for `http` block only that will redirect us to `https` automatically.

Answer (score 315):

I use the following to successfully redirect all pages of my domain from http to https:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Note this will redirect using the `301 'permanently moved'` redirect, which will help transfer your SEO rankings.

To redirect using the `302 'temporarily moved'` change `[R=302,L]`

Comment: this is more appropriate than the "hacky" accepted answer

Comment: In some cases the X-Forwarded-Proto is needed  `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]`

Answer (score 110):

This is the best for `www` and for HTTPS, for proxy and no proxy users.

```apacheconf
RewriteEngine On

### WWW & HTTPS

# ensure www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

### WWW & HTTPS
```

Comment: how to redirect to non-www?

Comment: this is by far the best answer for those where `%{HTTPS} off` isn't enough

Comment: Also, note that for those who wish to _remove_ `www` from the URL, the following should work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8699176/1035977 (just adapt it to use `https://...` instead of the `http://...` shown there)

Answer (score 18):

I force the https with following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 10):

Add this code at the end of your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Probably because mod_rewrite isn't enabled in this answer as it is in others.

Answer (score 6):

In cases where the HTTPS/SSL connection is ended at the load balancer and all traffic is sent to instances on port 80, the following rule works to redirect non-secure traffic.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Ensure the `mod_rewrite` module is loaded.

Answer (score 5):

Searching for the best way to redirect, i've found this (coming from html5boilerplate) :

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)                              |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Force client-side SSL redirection.
#
# If a user types `example.com` in their browser, even if the server
# redirects them to the secure version of the website, that still leaves
# a window of opportunity (the initial HTTP connection) for an attacker
# to downgrade or redirect the request.
#
# The following header ensures that browser will ONLY connect to your
# server via HTTPS, regardless of what the users type in the browser's
# address bar.
#
# (!) Remove the `includeSubDomains` optional directive if the website's
# subdomains are not using HTTPS.
#
# http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/transport-layer-security/
# https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-websec-strict-transport-sec-14#section-6.1
# http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2014/08/18/hsts-strict-transport-security-attacks-mitigations-deployment-https.aspx

Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=16070400; includeSubDomains"
```

Maybe it will help someone in 2017 ! :)

Comment: In 2017, this should be the accepted answer. But it should contain that to enable HSTS via .htacces file (question is tagged with this) you have to omit the IfModule tags. If you edit your answer with that I would gladly link to here from the accepted answer

Comment: Hello Jojo ! sorry for this late answer, you mean removing both `# <IfModule mod_headers.c>` and `# </IfModule>` lines ?

Comment: hey LIIT, yes that's what I meant.

Comment: While this is nice and does help to achieve or support the (probably) desired effect, this _does not_ redirect http requests to https, and as such, does not answer the question. It does only work if the client already accessed the site via HTTPS (within the max-age interval specified). So it should always be accompanied with a proper redirect.

Answer (score 5):

Insert this code in your .htaccess file. And it should work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} yourDomainName\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourDomainName.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 4):

This makes sure that redirects work for all combinations of intransparent proxies.

This includes the case *client <http> proxy <https> webserver*.

```
# behind proxy
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-PROTO} ^http$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# plain
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-PROTO} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} ^http$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with redirection also. I tried everything that was proposed on Stackoverflow. The one case I found by myself is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP:SSL} !=1 [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following to the top of the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what ended up working for me

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Forcing HTTPS with the `.htaccess` File**

**==> Redirect All Web Traffic :-**

To force all web traffic to use HTTPS, insert the following lines of code in the `.htaccess` file in your website’s root folder.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

**==> Redirect Only Specified Domain :-**

To force a specific domain to use HTTPS, use the following lines of code in the `.htaccess` file in your website’s root folder:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If this doesn’t work, try removing the first two lines.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

> Make sure to replace example.com with the domain name you’re trying
>   force to https. Additionally, you need to replace www.example.com with
>   your actual domain name.

**==> Redirect Specified Folder :-**

If you want to force SSL on a specific folder, insert the code below into a `.htaccess` file placed in that specific folder:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]
```

> Make sure you change the folder reference to the actual folder name.
>   Then be sure to replace www.example.com/folder with your actual domain
>   name and folder you want to force the SSL on.

Answer (score -1):

Replace your domain with `domainname.com` , it's working with me .

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainname\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domainname.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.