# All links are not redirecting to https from http

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have tried following;

If a user try to access my website http://test.com it will redirect to https://test.com but if a user try accessing internal page like http://test.com/test1 it doesn't redirect to https. I have tried following code in my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

**Full .htaccess file**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess redirect http to https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376219/htaccess-redirect-http-to-https)

Comment: @Marc i did checked that but that didn't solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Instead of testing for `!on` test for `off` -

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: What does the rest of your .htaccess file look like?

Comment: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

</IfModule>`

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments. Update your original post with the additional information.