# How to redirect from one http domain to another https domain via htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect

```
http://abc.one.com/mysettings/marks
```

to

```
https://xyz.two.com/mysettings/marks
```

I added below lines htaccess file but it doesn't seem to work. Please let me know where am I going wrong.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://abc.one.com/mysettings/marks [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://xyz.two.com/mysettings/marks [L,R=301]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess redirect http to https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376219/htaccess-redirect-http-to-https)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use;

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.one\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^mysettings/marks/?$ https://xyz.two.com/mysettings/marks [L,R=301]
```

Don't use URI in `HTTP_HOST` condition.

Answer (score 1):

Also use 301 redirect method. Because  Redirect 301 /old-page.html http://www.example.com/new-page.html