# How to set up .htaccess to redirect HTTP to HTTPS equivalent?

Tags: html, .htaccess, dreamhost

I’m using Dreamhost and have secure hosting and a secure certificate. I’m trying to redirect a plain HTTP site to an HTTPS site. I’m a bit confused about doing it.

I want to make `http://www.example.com/` redirect to `https://www.example.com/`

What do I put in what file to make it work?

Comment: Ok you want to google `htaccess redirect http to https`

Comment: There is already a question on here with an answer. Posting an answer would not be the correct thing to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376219/htaccess-redirect-http-to-https

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work. While you indicate `.htaccess` the concept is connected to Apache rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Just place that in your `.htaccess` file and all non-HTTPS requests will be directed to the HTTPS.

The way you can test this is to use `curl` like this; of course change `http://www.example.com` to match your actual domain name/host name.:

```
curl -I -L http://www.example.com
```

The `-I` flag tells `curl` just to send back headers and the `-L` tells `curl` to follow redirects. If you have that `.htaccess` setup correctly, then you will see the first hop to the non-HTTPS site and then a redirect—managed by the `.htaccess` rewrite rules—sending it to the next hop on the HTTPS site.

#### 301 versus 302 redirects.

Just one small note regarding server response messages and potential SEO stuff: When you use that final Apache rewrite rule as pictured, the default server response code would be:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
```

A [302 HTTP response](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3) is considered a temporary redirect. If you absolutely, positively always want plain-HTTP traffic to go to the HTTPS equivalent on the same server, you should be sending out a [301 HTTP response](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2) which is a permanent redirect. To use that Apache rewrite rule to send a 301 code, just tweak the last line so it all looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

After doing that the response should be:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
```

And all should be good. But—and not to jump down a weird rabbit hole—Google seems to understand that most people mistakenly send 302 headers when they mean 301, so it seems—[according to this article](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-302-301-permanent-redirect-21045.html)—Google factors in 302 redirects plus some kind of time range. And if you send enough 302s over a certain period of time Google will infer the change is permanent and treat that 302 as a 301.

Slightly confusing but at the end of the day, if you mean to make a redirect permanent, then *always* set 301 response headers to make everyone’s life easier.

Answer (score 2):

In your .htaccess, put:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.boy.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You just have to make sure your apache site definition is also listening to port 443 for https