# Wants to redirect Drupal Website from http to https

Tags: php, drupal

I have installed the secure certificate on my website.Both versions are running, I want website automatically redirects to https.
The website is created in Drupal.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=drupal+http+https --> https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24072/how-to-simply-make-the-whole-site-https

Comment: shall I copy paste this ?
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Comment: You should read and understand the documentation. I can't answer "shall I copy paste this", as I don't even know a) what webserver you're using (that'll only work for Apache) nor b) where you plan to paste it *to*.

Comment: I am using apache server

Comment: Then follow the instructions on https://www.drupal.org/https-information for Apache.

Comment: It's better to solve redirection with vhost config file, but if not possible .htaccess is also an option. Explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376219/htaccess-redirect-http-to-https

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to .htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine on
    # Redirect to HTTPS
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```