# .htaccess not redirecting http to https

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have domain [www.supergenscript.com](http://www.supergenscript.com) hosted on a cloud server where only an under construction index page is uploaded. There was no .htaccess file present so I created a .htaccess file and uploaded it in the server using filezilla. I want to redirect my website from http to https automatically. These are the contents of my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?supergenscript\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.supergenscript.com/$1 [R=301, L]
```

Nothing else except these lines of codes is written there. I expected this to work but this is not redirecting my domain to https automatically. Please help me with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess redirect http to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376219/htaccess-redirect-http-to-https)

Comment: That should work. What is your Apache version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Upload the .htaccess to your root directory.

**Line 1:** Checks the module - mod_rewrite is activated.

**Line 2:** Enables the Rewrite Engine.

**Line 3:** Checks if HTTPS-Protocol is switched on, if not then execute the contents of line 4.

**Line 4:** Redirects all requests to HTTPS via status code 301 = (permanent redirect).

**Line 5:** Close - mod_rewrite!

Comment: replaced my previous code with this code.. still its not redirecting.. you can check my URL.. why its not working man I am just getting frustrated as this SHOULD WORK.. !!

Comment: **Calm down!** :) It's part of the job. :) I visit your site and the redirect is running fine. **Can it be that you didn't delete your cache?** If you use a Windows-System clear your cache with "**cmd**" "**ipconfig /flushdns**" and clear your Browser-Cache. If it was not, add a comment which OS (Debian 8, NGINX ...) you use and upload the htaccess to your root directory. I'll check it later.

Comment: I see that you use Cloudflare-Nginx. If you have an error 525, the ssl handshake failed. https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200278659-Error-525-SSL-handshake-failed

Comment: The redirect is now working fine because I have configured it using CloudFlare. They had an option to "Always use HTTPS" in their SSL settings which I noticed later on. I further removed that htaccess file as it was not required anymore at this moment. Thanks for your help. Your answer is correct but for a website which is normally hosted without using CloudFlare. As this will help others I will accept it. Thanks again :)