# htaccess force https across domain with Angular app in subdirectory

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am a bit out of my depth when it comes to most server tasks so bear with me on my descriptions and understanding...

I am trying to use htaccess to force https across domain with Angular app in a subdirectory.

**Project structure**

```
/ public
  - .htaccess
  - index.html
  - styles.css
  - main.js
  - etc...
  / admin (angular app)
    - .htaccess
    - index.html
    - etc...
```

I am trying to force https across the whole domain while still being able to deep link to the /admin (angular) routes.

**/public/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.^site\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.site.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
```

**/public/admin/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
```

All /admin routes are still accessible via plain http and are not redirected. I have tried various combinations of ${SERVER_PORT} & ${HTTPS} but these never trigger. It always seems to return port 80 and https off and causes "too many redirects".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess not redirecting http to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45665554/htaccess-not-redirecting-http-to-https)

Comment: @akond that doesn't address my issues (unless I'm not understanding why?). HTTPS redirect works on the root domain but not the /admin subdirectory.