# convert mix content http to https

Tags: html, .htaccess, http, ssl, ssl-certificate

I recently added a ssl certificate to my website. Now the problem is that some of the elements like images, fonts etc. are external content which is using http in `"src=http://example.com/jpg"` tag.

I know I can solve the problem by just replacing `http` with `https` in my elements tag but I have at-least 133 web-pages that will take a while to do it manually.

Is there any other alternative that I can use?

Can I use `.htaccess` for this problem?

note - I am using cpanel hosting

Comment: Sure there's a way; see [.htaccess redirect http to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376219/htaccess-redirect-http-to-https) for example. I wouldn't recommend it though, it would cause confusion. Replacing "http" by "https" would be much more straightforward, and maintainable.

Comment: That is simply forcing HTTPs @MrLister - I think the OP is referring to links that they have coded into the site. So therefore requests would be loaded in HTTP even if the site is HTTPs and therefore cause an insecure connection. So really I think you need to manually change those links that you have coded in.

Comment: @Lag That's what I was referring to as well; my apologies if I was ambiguous.

Comment: Yes, here I am talking the links that are coded into the site

Comment: In that case Arp, I'm sorry to tell you that the best thing for you to do is change them manually. Since they are coded in there is no real way to make a bulk change to this. Not through `.htaccess` anyway. Perhaps if you wrote a script to do this for you, then maybe you could automate it.

Comment: Actually the index file is written in PHP  ( i .e  index.php) and I am not sure how to do that in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
RewriteEngine On

### WWW & HTTPS

# ensure www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

### WWW & HTTPS
```

Answer (score 0):

`.htaccess` is not going to help you here as it is used for redirecting `http` to `https` in websites.

as you are using cpanel that means you dont have access to your root server therefore your only option is to manually convert `http` to `https`.