# How redirect HTTP call to HTTPS for webservice in codeigniter?

Tags: .htaccess, web-services, codeigniter, http, https

Early my site has no SSL certificate so baseurl for webservice was `http://test.com/webservice/index.php`. Now I am going to move my site to `HTTPS`.
So when I tested webservice. All webservice showing `unknown method`. The base_url is hardcoded in android and iOS. So is there any way to redirect the `http` call to `https`. Otherwise app will be crashed. Whether Writing redirection in `.htaccess` file
can solve this issue.

Comment: If it were a webpage there are a few tricks you can use. Since you "hardcoded" the url in your apps I worry you painted yourself into a corner. I'm curious myself if there is a solution...

Comment: you can check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376219/htaccess-redirect-http-to-https

Answer (score 0):

`.htaccess` can be used to force `https`. The following usually works for CodeIgniter on Apache.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I contacted the server support team and they have done.