# http to https redirection is not working in angular 6 using htaccess

Tags: angular, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect my website to https://www using htaccess 301 permanent redirection rules.

I am using the below code in my htaccess file in Angular 6 build version.

Path: `/mysite/dist/myfolder/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourwebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

The above code works when I open https://example.com then it redirects to https://www.example.com. This is fine.

But when I try to open example.com or http://example.com then it does not redirect to https://www.example.com.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess redirect http to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376219/htaccess-redirect-http-to-https)

Comment: you mean two .htaccess file in it

Answer (score 2):

Just need to add HTTPS rewrite rule.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```