# How to redirect site URLs to https://example.com

Tags: apache

How to redirect from :

- `https://www.example.com`
- `http://www.example.com`
- `http://example.com`

to :

- `https://example.com`

How can I do this with `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.htaccess redirect http to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376219/htaccess-redirect-http-to-https)

Comment: no that question is different

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the best answer to my question :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It supported all of positions that I said.

You can test it in :
[Test .htaccess](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

so you can redirect from :

- `https://www.example.com`
- `http://www.example.com`
- `http://example.com`

to :

- `https://example.com`

**with that code.**

Comment: This will create a "redirect-loop" since the second rule redirects to itself. (The MWL htaccess tester is not able to catch this.) @menasoft had already posted an acceptable solution and you seem to have just copied it and reversed the two rules - which makes no difference whatsoever. (?)

Comment: it is the best solution to do it. I tested it.

Comment: How did you "test" it? The directives you posted are obviously wrong - they can not possibly work as written. As noted in my comment, the directives you've posted will result in an endless redirect-loop (if they are executed at all), because the second rule redirects the canonical hostname (ie. `example.com` - no www) to itself. If, however, HTTP and HTTPS resolve to different hosts and these directives are on the HTTP host then there will be no "loop", but then requests to the non-canonical hostname on HTTPS won't be canonicalised. (?!)

Comment: Even using the MWL `.htaccess` tester that you referenced you can still deduce the error... when you request `https://example.com/foo` you can see that it will generate a "redirect loop" because the "output URL" is the same as the "input URL".... https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=4c6d6cd0-fb9d-4d18-9f86-c3484e8f455d / When you request `https://example.com/foo` (ie. the canonical scheme + hostname) there should be "no" output - it should not do anything.

Comment: I tested it again it worked perfect.when you put https:// example. com the output is https:// example. com too so it working perfect

Comment: When you say, "tested", do you mean in that testing tool, or on a real server? If the output (from that "testing tool") is the same as the input then that is an error - it will result in an endless redirect loop. When you request the canonical URL there should be "no" output at all - it should not do anything.

Comment: I tested it in testing tool and real server. In both of them result was perfect

Comment: Testing tool is great. It can show you the output of the code and debugging it.

Comment: That "testing tool" has a lot of bugs. (But you are misinterpreting the results of that tool in this case.) There's no way the code you posted can work on a "real" server.

Comment: I said I tested it in real server and it worked perfectttttttt

Answer (score 1):

you can do that by add this code to .htacces file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

note if you want remove www from url

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Are you sure that code support all of positions that I said??

Comment: i have already use it on more than projecct and work perfectly

Comment: please look at my edit in your answer and if is it correct please approve it

Comment: So how can I do it??

Comment: i have already updated answers you can try it

Comment: It not support all of position that I said

Answer (score 0):

Define a middleware for removing *www* from the url using below command `php artisan make:middleware RedirectToNonWwwMiddleware` and write below code in handle method of that middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (substr($request->header('host'), 0, 4) == 'www.') {
            $request->headers->set('host', config('app.url'));
            $trailing = $request->path() == '/' ? '' : '/';
            return \Redirect::to(config('app.url') . $trailing . $request->path());
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Add the middleware to the array of `$middleware` inside `app\Http\Kernel.php` file like below

```
protected $middleware = [

    // Other middlewares ...

    \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectToNonWwwMiddleware::class,
];
```

Define the url inside your *.env* file with **https** like below

```sh
APP_URL=https://example.com
```

At last clear the config cache by running `php artisan config:clear`.

Comment: Thank you but I want do it by .htaccess file

Comment: You're welcome. You can also use spatie's package for this purpose [laravel-missing-page-redirector](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-missing-page-redirector)

Comment: thanks but it is not useful for me