# htaccess remove www and redirect to accessed url

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter framework i need to force to remove www from the url so I am using this code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|images|js|plugins|scripts|fancybox|uploads|mobile|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /framework/index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI}/$1 [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

This code is forcing removal of www. but the problem is when a user access a link with www

```
eg:www.mydomain.com/framework/article/sometestarticle368/
```

It is redirecting to

```
www.mydomain.com/framework/
```

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Please refer this-->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515081/htaccess-remove-www-from-url-directories

Comment: I tried that thing also but it is not working. always redirecting to www.mydomain.com/framework/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the order of your rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI}/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|images|js|plugins|scripts|fancybox|uploads|mobile|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /framework/index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Otherwise your 2nd rules runs first and change the URI to `/framework/...` before the www removal rule..

Comment: Thanks for your replay this code is not working with ajax calls with www to this domain. how can i fix this?

Comment: Apache doesn't know the difference between a Ajax request and regular web request. What exactly is not working in your AJAX call, can you check from Firebug and let me know? Also let me know what is full URL of your AJAX call and does it do any POST operation?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.yoursite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

- Thanks