# How to remove www from address by htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a domain which is accessible on `http://www.example.com`.

I want to remove the `www.` part.
I am using a .htaccess file, but it isn't working.

```
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
 RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess Remove WWW from URL + Directories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515081/htaccess-remove-www-from-url-directories) (the **first** result on Google for "*htaccess remove www*")

Comment: What's "not working" about it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place this rule in your DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: This would also match `http://foo.com/request=wwweeeeeeee` because you didn't use `^`.