# .htaccess remove http://www from url

Tags: .htaccess

I want that a url of the form

```
http://www.example.com
```

redirects to

```
example.com
```

How can I achive this? I found that [.htaccess Remove WWW from URL + Directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515081/htaccess-remove-www-from-url-directories) comes pretty close to my question, but I do not know how to change it appropriately.

Comment: If you remove the "http://" then it will no longer be a URL.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To remove www ,you can use :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [NE,L,R]
```