# Prevent HREF tag from adding 'www' to beginning of url

Tags: html, href

I have the following link on my website:

```
<a href="http://somepage.com" target="_blank"> Some Page </a>
```

When clicked, it is automatically converted to "http://www.somepage.com", however the page cannot be accessed from that URL.

How do I prevent the 'www' from being added?

Comment: looks like a redirect one the other side / on the webserver (`.htaccess`). the webserver of the website is redirecting / adding the `www` part.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515081/htaccess-remove-www-from-url-directories

Comment: This is not an html issue. It could be a redirect on the target.

Comment: The .htaccess solution worked for me, thanks.