# remove www from URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My site has been hosted on https://example.com

But the problem is when i try to access it  with https://www.example.com it still accessible. But i don't want to user to  access the site with www instead of it i want to redirect it to https://example.com . How do i make it happen?

Here is the current .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess Remove WWW from URL + Directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515081/htaccess-remove-www-from-url-directories)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```