Issue with redirects when URL has suffix
I have .htaccess rules in place that:

Map http to https
Map the domain 59sportfury.net to 59plymouth.net
Strips www. if present
appends /59forum to the URL (where my phpBB board resides)

This all works fine.  However, if the URL contains anything after .net the rules above are not applied, e.g.,
http://www.59sportfury.net/59forum

or
http://www.59plymouth.net/59forum/viewtopic.php?t=4190 (where one post might reference another post)

If anything follows ".net" in the URL, the .htaccess rules are ignored.  Is there a way to fix this?
Here are the rules in my .htaccess file:
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^59sportfury\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.59sportfury\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/59plymouth\.net\/59forum" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^59plymouth\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.59plymouth\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/59plymouth\.net\/59forum" [R=301,L]


(And yes, once I've got this sorted, I plan to move the rules into httpd.conf.)

This regex in RewriteRule "^/?$" may be the reason of your faulty behaviour. Basically it means to stop after the first eventual slash. Try to put "(.*)" instead.

Actually that matching pattern only matches an empty subject or a subject holding only a single slash. Those patterns will never match anything but a requiest to the base URL. And thus those rules will never get applied, except for requests to the base URL.

Thanks @Azog.  I tested "(.*)" here:  https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=19e6a025-7cf1-48f3-8a59-dad53df10220
But it produced https://www.59sportfury.net/59forum

Have a look at that answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8699176/6270743
The %1 refers to the capturing group (.*)

Well, that looks to be a step in the right direction, @Azog; although, I still want www.59sportfury.net -> 59plymouth.net (as well as www.59plymouth.net -> 59plymouth.net).  But {REQUEST_URI} could be null, in which case I want /59forum appended; or, not null, in which case I want {REQUEST_URI} appended (because it already contains /59forum, as well as an additional string).  It needs to be conditional.
